# Toggle between vim and non-vim controls

Tags: macvim, macos

How can you get a running instance of Vim to stop using all custom mappings, and possibly even some defaults, and start using a new set of mappings.  And then be able to toggle back.  Specifically, I'd like to switch to basic [standard text-editing keyboard shortcuts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Table_of_keyboard_shortcuts#Text_editing) of one or more operating systems/environments: Mac, Windows, KDE, Gnome, Chrome.

As seen in the comments, the following topics might provide hints, but I wasn't able to make progress: `:help :behave`, `:help mswin.vim`, or `:help 'insertmode'`

Comment: I'm going to close this as off-topic since it doesn't appear to be about vim ([help/on-topic]), but you may be interested in `:help :behave`, `:help mswin.vim`, and `:help 'insertmode'`.

Comment: RE: [so] vs. [vi.se], they are not linked. Generally speaking cross-posting is frowned upon. You should ask those kinds of questions on [meta], though, not in a Q on the main site.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about Vi & Vim as defined in the help center (see previous comments).

Comment: Thank you Ben, I posted [here](https://vi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1570/how-to-toggle-between-vim-and-non-vim-controls).

Comment: Oh no, sorry for the ambiguity… I meant that you should ask questions about crossposting and site policy on meta… not qs about the editor :( Possibly the best place for your question is chat, which you don’t yet have access to I think